# Custom events without trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript function that I use to create a basic event handler for images being loaded in any given container...

```
function onImagesLoaded($container, callback) {
    var $images = $container.find("img");
    var imgCount = $images.length;
    if (!imgCount) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $images.each(function () {
            $(this).one("load error", function () {
                imgCount--;
                if (imgCount == 0) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
    }
}
```

I currently call that with something like this...

```
onImagesLoaded($("div.image-container"), function() {
    console.log("Images loaded");
});
```

This is fine and it works, but I want to be able to attach it to elements like this...

```
$("div.image-container").on("imagesloaded", function() {
    console.log("Images loaded");
});
```

This isn't a *"my code doesn't work - please fix it"* type of question, because it does work and does exactly what I want, functionality-wise.  I'm asking this question as I can't find any help relating to how to do it the way I want to do it and I'm trying to learn something new.  Everything I've read about jQuery custom events requires you to manually trigger them, and that's not what I'm trying to do here.

I'm saying that I want to attach an event handler to an element and then assign my function to that element *because* of that event handler.  Maybe I need to parse the elements in the DOM manually to do this - I don't know.

Can anyone at least point me in the direction of how this can be done (if it can)?

**Edit**

I started working on overriding the existing `on()` function in a similar way to how KevinB suggested below.  The code he supplied covered a couple of issues I had with my version so I merged the two together and came up with a working version....

```
var $_on = $.fn.on

$.fn.on = function () {
    switch (arguments[0]) {
        case "imagesloaded":
            onImagesLoaded(this, arguments[1]);
            break;
        default:
            return $_on.apply(this, arguments);
            break;
    }
};
```

Using that I can now attach custom event handlers using `.on()`, just as I said I wanted in the question above.

In hindsight, the question title was worded badly.  It should have been about just that - overriding `on()`.

**Another Edit**

After further thought on the matter I decided to create a `createEvent()` method so I could add custom events to jQuery's `on()` without hassle.  If anyone comes across this page and is looking for that, you can find it here...

http://johncmolyneux.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/how-to-override-jquery-on-and-add.html

There's also a link on that page to the jquery.extend library on GitHub, which I will add to whenever I make something that I think should be added.

Comment: Just attaching an event to an element does nothing until you trigger said event. You must cause the onImagesLoaded method to fire, and have it trigger the event. You could turn your function into a plugin and use it like this: `$("someselector").on("imagesloaded",handler).loadImages()`

Comment: That's my point, @KevinB.  With the example I've given above it would be silly to try and create a trigger for a custom event, as it could be attached to every single element in the page that can have child elements.

Comment: Sorry - yeah, we're both typing at the same time :)

Comment: It's difficult to explain, but what I really want is to somehow capture the fact that `.on("imageloaded")` has been used, and then manually assign my function to the selected element.  I'm not sure how your example relates to that.

Comment: Incidentally, the only answer I've come up with myself is to use `$.fn.onImagesLoaded()`.  I'm more asking if this can be done the way I'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would turn it into a plugin and use it this way:

```
$.loadImages = function($images, callback) {        
    var imgCount = $images.length;
    if (!imgCount) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $images.each(function () {
            /*$(this).one("load error", function () {
                imgCount--;
                if (imgCount == 0) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();*/
            var img = new Image();
            $(img).on("load error", function(){
                imgCount--;
                if (imgCount == 0) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            img.src = this.src;
        });
    }
};
$.fn.loadImages = function (callback) {
    var $images = this.find("img").addBack().filter("img");
    var self = this;
    $.loadImages($images,function(){
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback();
        }
        self.trigger("imagesLoaded");
    });
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$.loadImages($("div.image-container").find("img"), function() {
    console.log("Images loaded");
});
```

or you can use it like this:

```
$("div.image-container").on("imagesLoaded",function(){
    console.log("Images loaded");
}).loadImages();
```

or even like this:

```
$("div.image-container").loadImages(function(){
    console.log("Images loaded");
});
```

this works too:

```
$("div.image-container img").loadImages(function(){
    console.log("Images loaded");
});
```

There is no way of making .on automatically cause the plugin to run without monkeypatching .on, which is usually a bad idea. It might look something like this:

```
var oldOn = $.fn.on

$.fn.on = function() {
    var ret = oldOn.apply(this,arguments);
    if (arguments[0] == "imagesloaded") {
        var self = this;
        onImagesLoaded(this,function(){
            self.trigger("imagesloaded");
        });
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: you may also need to take into account the fact that the image might be loaded before the dom ready event is fired... so the `load error` event will not get triggered

Comment: I would solve that by creating new images and preloading that way, i just didn't want to rewrite everything he did

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I think this is the route I'm going to end up going down, which is what I expected.  I ideally wanted to find out that there is a way of using `on`, without "monkeypatching it" :p

Comment: Actually... he does seem to be somewhat taking that into account.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I do check to see if the image is loaded - `if (this.complete) $(this).load();`

Comment: @both, i updated the preloading to better(my opinion) handle cached images

Comment: I'd actually started working on overriding the `on()` function before I saw this - we were very close in what we were doing.  This isn't exactly how I did it so I'll add mine into the question, but accept this as an answer.  Thanks for your help :)